# Is $(9,18X-3)$ a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

My reasoning is as follows:

$\mathbb{Z}[X]\Big/(9,18X-3) \cong \left(\mathbb{Z}\Big/\mathbb{9Z}\right)[X]\Big/(\overline{18}X-\overline{3}) = \left(\mathbb{Z}\Big/\mathbb{9Z}\right)[X]\Big/(\overline{6}) \cong \left(\mathbb{Z}\Big/\mathbb{3Z}\right)[X]$

Since $\left(\mathbb{Z}\Big/\mathbb{3Z}\right)[X]$ is an integral domain $(9,18X-3)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Is this correct?

Comment: Easier to first note $\,(9,18x-3) = (9,3) = (3)\ $

Comment: You two, thank you very much.